# Import package installed from github

Tags: node.js, npm, import, package

I just installed a package that is not in npm registry via github like this

```
yarn add git+https://github.com/azazdeaz/react-color-picker-wheel.git
```

Now I can see it in my package.json file like this

```
"react-color-picker-wheel": "git+https://github.com/azazdeaz/react-color-picker-wheel.git"
```

However when I import it like this

```
import ColorPickerWheel from 'react-color-picker-wheel'
```

I get this error 
`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react-color-picker-wheel'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `main` property of the [package.json](https://github.com/azazdeaz/react-color-picker-wheel/blob/master/package.json#L5) in the Github repo is set to `./lib/index.js` but that file does not exist in the repository.

When you import that module, it tries to resolve the file `./lib/index.js` relative to the `node_modules/react-color-picker` directory.

You could submit a PR to update the `package.json`'s main property to refer to the correct file (`./src/index.js`, or fork the repository and update the Github url to your repo's URL. It's worth checking out the NPM docs about the `main` property as well :)

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main